# Class static function variable reference in PHP

Tags: php, class

PHP 7.

I'm trying to use the same class method in different situations. The first time, when the user is creating a new entry into the database, and I draw the admin page with empty values. It has been created as the following.

```
$classname::drawAdmin(FALSE);
```

$classname is a variable, since I don't know in advance which classes will be used on the webpage (Ikr?), and have to get it from the database.

Inside the method, it checks if it's creating a new object, or reusing an existing one.

```
static function drawAdmin( $mod = FALSE ) {
        print 'Technology<input type="text" name="technology" value="'.($mod?$this->technology:"").'" /><br />';
etc...
}
```

It works well when a new entry is created, check if it's trying to modify, if not, create an input with no value, else it is writing the objects datas into the values.

However it does not work when I create a new object, and try to modify it's data.

```
$class = new $row['class_name']($_GET['id']);
$class->drawAdmin(TRUE);
```

(The class' constructor sanitizes the $_GET array.)

In this case, I receive an error message:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in [censored]/class.phone.php on line 932
```

even if the object was created correctly, and existing (checked with var_dump).

Haha, jokes on me, it's a static method, so I can't use $this! However, when I change the print to:

```
static function drawAdmin( $mod = FALSE ) {
        print 'Technology<input type="text" name="technology" value="'.($mod?self::technology:"").'" /><br />';
etc...
}
```

I still get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'technology' in [censored]/class.phone.php on line 932
```

and if I add the (protected) variables to static, I can't use them anymore with $this->.

Is there any way, that I could use the same class variables with both object and without object contexts?

Comment: The first example that you claim works well, cannot work: There is no `$this` inside a static method.

Comment: I do not use `$this` in the first example. That's why it works.

Comment: Certainly you can use static members inside an objects method, _if you use the correct syntax_.

Comment: @arkascha Which is?

Comment: Bottom line, you can't do this You can't use `$this` is a static method. The entire post implies some generally bad design in the application that might be worth resolving sooner rather than later. (Just imo)

Comment: Static properties are `self::$technology`, note that `$` after `::`.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, but if you set / manipulate it in the constructor - which is what I assume reading the OP's post - you are in for a lot of pain :-)

Comment: @kry "I do not use $this in the first example"....err... what is `$this->technology` in that example, then?

Comment: @ADyson Think OP means that the $this isn't run in the first scenario, so doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @ADyson That only runs for if the `$mod == TRUE`. Since it's `FALSE` in the first example (and also the default) it never runs, just concatenates an empty string.

Comment: @JonStirling ah yes, that would be the case. But still, putting it in there doesn't make any sense, when $mod is true it'll fall over. Which is what is being discussed. Sorry, think I've made a bit of a pointless intervention

Comment: buggy code is still buggy code, even if that specific path is not executed at one specific time.

Comment: I think you could keep the method static, but if you're editing an existing object, you'd have to pass an actual instance of the same class into the method as optional second parameter, to be used when $mod is true, and then use the "technology" value from that instance.

Comment: @ADyson You mean, like `drawAdmin($mod=FALSE, $class=NULL) { ($mod?$class->getTechnology():"")}` and call it like `$class->drawAdmin(TRUE, $class);` ?

Comment: @ADyson omg, it actually works! I was looking for this solution thanks! (If you post and answer, I will gladly accept it.)

Comment: @kry done, thanks in advance... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could keep the method static, but if you're editing an existing object, you'd have to pass an actual instance of the same class into the method as optional second parameter, to be used when $mod is true, and then use the "technology" value from that instance.

For example:

```
static fuction drawAdmin($mod=FALSE, $class=NULL) { 
        print 'Technology<input type="text" name="technology" value="'.($mod?$class->getTechnology():"").'" /><br />';
}
```

and then in the case of it being a modification, call it like this:

```
$class->drawAdmin(TRUE, $class);
```

Comment: Missed the arrow from the class method.